# Jacoco coverage ratio on 0.0

Tags: java, jacoco

I have a problem with jacoco plugin in maven. Although i have some test lines in test files my coverage ratio is on 0.0. I dont know what can i do to make this work.

I've tried making changes in pom.xml from my friends pom, but this also doesn't work

here is the output from making maven.install:

```
--- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:check (default-check) @ Sudoku ---
Loading execution data file D:\xd\inf\4 semestr\Programowanie Komponentowe\prokom_2019_lch_sr_12_01\target\jacoco.exec
Analyzed bundle 'Sudoku' with 8 classes
Rule violated for bundle Sudoku: complexity covered ratio is 0.000000, but expected minimum is 0.600000
```

here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.progkomp.Sudoku</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sudoku</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>sudoku</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>checkstyle</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>checkstyle</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.600000</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

In test files i have about 100 lines with lots of asserts, so the problem is only with the plugin.

Comment: You should also explain how you have configured Jacoco to your editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a long time ago, however the problem was that test classes didn't ended with suffix Test. Pretty obvious, but not at that time when I was second year IT student :)

Answer (score 2):

> In test files i have about 100 lines with lots of asserts, so the problem is only with the plugin.

The problem is clearly not "only with the plugin" and `pom.xml` is not enough to demonstrate your problem, because after addition of

`src/main/java/Example.java`

```java
class Example {
}
```

and `src/main/java/ExampleTest.java`

```java
public class ExampleTest {
  @org.junit.Test
  public void test() {
    new Example();
  }
}
```

and `checkstyle.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
</module>
```

with exactly the same `pom.xml`
execution of `mvn clean install`
works perfectly fine:

```
...
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:check (default-check) @ Sudoku ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /private/tmp/j/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'Sudoku' with 1 classes
[INFO] All coverage checks have been met.
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.071 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-25T15:45:10+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide **complete verifiable** example with all parts needed to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 0.0 coverage, because all my Test classes lack the Public scope, (they were private by default)